# Extending Backbone Views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have searched a lot but haven't been able to find a suitable answer.
I'm trying to override a function defined in a Marionette CompositeView. I extended the composite view with a new class with function that should overwrite the default, everything works as expected, but problem is that the parent/original class(ClassA) still calls the old function instead of the new one(ClassB)

```
var ClassA = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.onValueAdded();
        // now the onValueAdded of ClassB should be called, or at least this is what im trying to accomplish
    },
    onValueAdded: function () {

    }
});

var ClassB = ClassA.extend({
    onValueAdded: function () {
        alert('this should get fired');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this just now locally and if I do `new ClassB()` then the `onValueAdded` function defined in `ClassB` get's called as expected. and when I do `new ClassA()` the one in `ClassA` get's called. Could you illustrate the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Of course `ClassA` would call `ClassA#onValueAdded`, `ClassA` knows nothing of its subclass `ClassB` and `B = A.extend({...})` doesn't alter `A` in any way (when of course `extend` is Backbone's "subclassing" `extend` rather than [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) or [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)). Are you actually trying to monkey patch `ClassA` to replace its `onValueAdded` with one of your own?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to completely replace onValueAdded with another one of my own. without any old trigger events to call the old (ClassA) function

Comment: I was just able to get the results your were looking for with the code you provided. Could you include the code you use to instantiate?

Answer (score 0):

When I instantiate ClassB I get the right alert ('this should get fired')

```
var c = new ClassB();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1380/